# VB6 Error: Run-time Error '-2146232576 (80131700)' Automation Error

Tags: c#, com, vb6, windows-xp, vb6-migration

I understand this question has few answers on the web and stackoverflow; but it is around MS Word and Excel and I am using neither.

I have a C# ComVisible dll which adds two numbers and I am calling it from a VB6 application. I have used interfacing, generated GUIDs, etc and it works perfectly fine in Windows 7 environment which has .Net Framework 4.5 installed.
Note: My C# dll is marked to target .Net 3.5 and above.

I do the same thing on XP which has .Net 4 ( 4 Client Profile and 4 Extended) installed.
I have registered the dll using "regasm /codebase". Whenever I **create the object** of my dll in the XP machine, it throws an error:
**Run-time Error '-2146232576 (80131700)' Automation Error**

What could be wrong in the configuration which works fine on Windows 7 but not on XP ?

Thanks for your comments in advance.

Comment: I have tried building the dll specifically for x86 environment - but it still does not work.

Comment: 0x80131700 = CLR_E_SHIM_RUNTIMELOAD = "Failed to load the runtime".  You used the wrong version of Regasm.exe.  Pretty hard to do, don't just copy it from one machine to another.  Use C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Regasm.exe to ensure you actually use .NET 4

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.

For some reason, having just .Net 4.0 on XP is not sufficient.
I hd to install .Net 3.5 too for this to work correctly.
Thanks.